# Buttons not working inside iframe that open blazor page

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Buttons not working inside iframe that open blazor page
,i added buttons that call method in parent component (save) ,it works fine without iframe but it doesn't work in iframe

```html
<td>
<button @onclick="@(e => { currency.ViewMode = "visible"; currency.EditMode = "collapse"; Save(currency.ISOCode, currency.Name, currency.MinorUnit, false); })" class="btn btn-primary m-1">Save</button>
<button @onclick="@(e => { currency.ViewMode = "visible"; currency.EditMode = "collapse"; })" class="btn btn-primary m-1">Cancel</button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Iframes in combination with Blazor. Last time I used an Iframe was 5 years ago. An Iframe is by definition a seperate page. Because Blazor is a SPA (Single Page Application), that is probably the problem. It is not designed to work with an Iframe.